# Failure not working ASP.NET MVC Ajax JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The following is my ajax call which is working fine but its always success.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@(Request.RawUrl + "/postcomment")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
```

How can I cause the failure function to be activated.  In the controller class, I'm doing

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Error message");
```

But in the failure message box doesn't appear, what do I need to do to get failure to work and display a message.

Comment: It's `error` not `failure`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please replace `failure` with `error`:

```
error: function(response) {
  alert(response.d);
}
```

Comment: I'd seen failure somewhere and began using that.  I've updated the answer with the correct property I should've been using.  statusText is the right property.  Accept the edit and I'll mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the status code callback. Where did you get failure callback from? There is only an `error` callback.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    500: function() {
      alert( "error" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't remember why I was using failure, must've seen it somewhere on the internet somewhere and just copied it.